# xubuntu - disable the switch-window pop-up

Tags: ubuntu, popupwindow

i'd like to disable the switch window pop-up (alt+tab) on a xubuntu-machine for a project. Did anybody achieve this already and which steps did you take?

I only got so far to change the layout and style of the pop-up but i have not been able to deactivate it entirely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable keyboard shortcuts in : 'settings manager -> window manager -> keyboard'

Comment: Thanks Tim, but my issue lies in the fact, that I still want to use the feature of switching the windows - only without the pop-up.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your question correctly. You could try to disable the alt tap competly and make a new shortuct that does the same thing with the same shortcut, maybe it will remove the notification.